# Kotlin: How to Lazy Initialization a Vector

Tags: kotlin

When I lazy initialise a vector. I could do it for normal Object class as below.

```
val mPagerAdapter: PagerAdapter by lazy {
    PagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, fragments, mTabsName)
}
```

However, when I lazy initialise a Vector variable as below

```
val fragments = Vector<Fragment>() by lazy {
    Vector<Fragment>()
}
```

It gave me error stating `Unresolve Reference: by`. How to fix this problem that I could lazy initialise it?

Comment: in the second snipped the syntax is wrong. The message could be probably more informative, like "property assignment is conflicts with property delegation"

Comment: Agree. The error message is not intuitive. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second case the syntax is noticeably different from the first snippet (you initialize your variable before `by`), compare to:

```
val fragments by lazy { Vector<Fragment>() }
```

Comment: Thanks! for the first one I just realise I could simplify to `val mPagerAdapter by lazy {
    PagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, fragments, mTabsName)
}`